# How transfer vertex animation (vertex shapeKeys) to 3dmax or unity3d?

Tags: file-format, blend-files

I have an object in a blender. We have object vertex animation (vertex shapeKeys). How can I transfer it to 3dmaks? Through some intermediate format? Only in 3dmaks a plugin for exporting vertex animation unity3d.

Comment: Have you tried the export mdd addon?